# How do I mock timer using jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How do use Jest to mock timer `context.getRemaining()` and mock `sendMessage()` when it has been called?

I want `context.getRemaining()` to be decreased by 9sec when `sendMessage()`has been called. `sendMessage()` will be called multiple time via while loop. It will start with 60,000ms.

```
exports.handler = async (context) => {
 while (true) {
    console.log(context.getRemaining());
    await sendMessage();
    if (context.getRemaining() < 13000) {
      break;
    }
 }

 return "FINISH";
}
```

Comment: Where does `sendMessage` come from? Also what is the purpose of the test?

Comment: `sendMessage` make API call (HTTP). Could mock `sendMessage` to return true which then `context.getRemaining()` reduce 9ms every time it call `sendMessage`

Comment: so is `sendMessage` being imported into the file directly? So what's the purpose of the test, to verify `sendMessage` is being called X times over a period of time?

Comment: `sendMessage` take about 9 seconds to make API request. That is why I want to mock `context.getRemaining()` to reduce by 9000ms (9 sec) when sendMessage has been called. As you can see `sendMessage()` will make multiple calls.  If `context.getRemaining()` is less than 13000 ms then it return FINISH.

Comment: is this part of a bigger test? I'm not quite I understand the value of mocking the delay of a request as the SUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jest.fn()` for `context.getRemaining` and provide multiple functions for it:

```
sendMessage = jest.fn(async () => {});
await handler({
    getRemaining: jest.fn()
        .mockReturnValueOnce(20000)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(10000),
});
expect(sendMessage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
```

When you write tests, usually it's better to avoid complex logic in the test code. For the mocks you can provide explicit return values. Else you'll need to write tests for your test code, which is bad.

Comment: Cool, that's one half of the problem solved, what about the other?

Comment: Is there a way to mock `sendMessage()` that has been called then reduce `getRemaining` ms